# Why does Clojure lack user defined reader macros?

Tags: clojure, language-design, reader-macro

As I understand it Clojure does not expose the reader macro table or allow user defined reader macros.

From http://clojure.org/reader:

```
The read table is currently not accessible to user programs.
```

I'm just wondering if there is a definitive or explicit statement (presumably from Rich Hickey) stating the rationale for leaving them out of Clojure.

Note I'm *not* asking if it is a good or bad thing that Clojure lacks user defined reader macros.  Just wondering why.

Comment: Some info here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/8RSLNWno0nU

Comment: @matt If you convert that to an answer I'm accept it as it is a direct answer to the question from Rich Hickey himself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/8RSLNWno0nU) in matt's comments, to quote the answer by Rich Hickey, the author of Clojure:

> I am unconvinced that reader macros are needed in Clojure at this 
>   time. They greatly reduce the readability of code that uses them (by 
>   people who otherwise know Clojure), encourage incompatible custom mini- 
>   languages and dialects (vs namespace-partitioned macros), and 
>   complicate loading and evaluation.
>
> To the extent I'm willing to accommodate common needs different from 
>   my own (e.g. regexes), I think many things that would otherwise have 
>   forced people to reader macros may end up in Clojure, where everyone 
>   can benefit from a common approach.
>
> Clojure is arguably a very simple language, and in that simplicity 
>   lies a different kind of power.
>
> I'm going to pass on pursuing this for now,
>
> Rich

Answer (score 4):

Speaking straight there are `Tagged Literals` that allow you to specify what to do with next form. For example, you can add

```
{to/u clojure.string/upper-case}
```

to `data_readers.clj` (see docs) and write something like this:

```
testapp.core> #to/u "asd"
"ASD"
```

but it's not so powerful as full support of reader macros, at least because of 
`The data reader function is invoked on the form AFTER it has been read as a normal Clojure data structure by the reader`.

I found this old log (don't ask me how) 
http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2008-11-06.html

where there is a discussion with Rich Hickey's thoughts about reader macros.