# can't use vector creation inside short-hand function definition

Tags: clojure

I'd like to do vector creation inside a function.

```
(map #([first %]) coll_of_tuples)
```

This gives the error

> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector 
>   clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

Any workaround besides using `list`? I'm looking for short notation.

Comment: Would this work `(map #(vector (first %)) coll_of_tuples)`?

Comment: Yes, that works. In this situation I don't require a vector. It's sad that other short-hand notations don't work inside `#()`.

Comment: Making them "work" would require changing the composability of Clojure's semantics, so this is *good*, not sad. `#()` is shorthand for function creation. Combining Clojure syntax as `#([...])` means to create a vector, then wrap in an invokable function. The invokable function you want is vector construction. The function for that is `vector`. +1 to peter's answer which says what you mean.

Comment: @AlexMiller I see why that didn't work. I was so focused on extracting the first "column" from data that I thought of `map_fn` as a final shape for the row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure: returning a vector from an anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921566/clojure-returning-a-vector-from-an-anonymous-function)

Comment: @glts I'm looking for short-hand notation. That question is related though. It has something that hasn't been said here: `(map #(identity [(first %)])` coll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a shorter version there is a few options:

```
(map #(-> [(first %)]) coll)

(map #(do [(first %)]) coll)

(map (juxt first) coll)
```

Comment: another one could be `(map (comp vector first) ...)`

Comment: While these are terse (I particularly like the juxt one), I find they are harder to understand at a glance.

Comment: The first and second versions are terse versions of precisely what I was trying to do and address the requirements for a `map_fn`.

Comment: @AlexMiller I think `juxt` is more confusing because only one value is considered, i.e. there is no juxtaposition.

Answer (score 2):

I like peter's answer in the comments of

```
(map #(vector (first %)) coll_of_tuples)
```

Or alternately

```
(map #(-> % first vector) coll_of_tuples)
```

Or leaning on FP more and anon fn less:

```
(map (comp vector first) coll_of_tuples)
```

If you instead prefer to think of this as extracting the first 1-length sequence from each, this is a seq-ier answer:

```
(map #(take 1 %) coll_of_tuples)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I needed the vector type I'd use `(map #(vector (first %)) coll_of_tuples)` as suggested by peter. So far it appears that `list` is the shortest notation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `for`, which is very similar to `map` except for giving a symbolic name to each element of the sequence in turn:

```
(for [tuple coll_of_tuples] 
  [(first tuple)])
```

This is not quite as minimal as some of the other solutions, but in some instances it is nice to have a named symbol like `tuple` instead of `%`.