# Clojure functions and thread macro

Tags: clojure

I am pretty new with Clojure language.

While reading about [Clojure functions](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions), I find the example `#([%])`. So I try to use it as follows:

```
(def test1 #([%]))
(test1 5)
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

which seems to be that it is trying to *invoke* the array I wanted to return.

After digging a while, I find a solution as follows:

```
(def test1 #(-> [%]))
(test1 5)
```

I would have some questions:

1. Why doesn't the `#([%])` work? What did I do with the expression `#([x])`?
2. In the correct example I am using the [thread-first macro](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros#thread-first). Based on its documentation, it is used to pass an argument to the next function, e.g. `(-> x (+ 1))`. In this case I do not even have a function to pass to; *what is the *next* function in this context? I can not realize *why* it solved my issue

Comment: the canonical would be `#(vector x)`. The answer

Comment: thanks @leetwinski, I am using those functions just for studying purpose. The  tutorial itself suggests to use the `vector` function.

Comment: Your main question is covered very thoroughly at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921566/clojure-returning-a-vector-from-an-anonymous-function. I'm not closing this as a duplicate though, because the additional discussion of `->` is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**

The syntax `#([%])` translates into: *"Create a function that when called will evaluate the expression `([%])` with `%` being the first (and only) argument passed to the function"*. This expression has the syntax of a function call with `[%]` being the function to be called. You can see what goes on using a `macroexpand`:

```
(macroexpand '#([%]))
;; => (fn* [p1__6926#] ([p1__6926#]))
```

The class of persistent vectors in clojure is `clojure.lang.PersistentVector`. They implement the `IFn` interface for arity 1, so that you can treat the vector as a function mapping an index to an element. But they do not implement arity 0, which is what you are trying to call. In other words, your code does not work:

```
(def test1 #([%]))
(test1 5) ;; ERROR
```

However, if you would pass the argument 0 to your function `[%]`, you would get back the element:

```
(def test1 #([%] 0))
(test1 5)
;; => 5
```

Do you see what happens? However, for the thing you are trying to do, there is a better way: The `[a b c]` syntax is just sugar for calling `(vector a b c)`. So to get something that works, you can just do

```
(def test1 vector)
(test1 5)
;; => [5]
```

**Question 2**

The thread-first macros has the syntax of `(-> x f0 f1 f2 ...)` where `x` is the initial value and `f0`, `f1` and so on are function calls with their first argument left out to be replaced by the value that is being piped through. Again we can use macroexpand to understand:

```
(macroexpand '(-> x f0 f1 f2))
;; => (f2 (f1 (f0 x)))
```

But in your case, the function calls are left out. To analyze your second example, we need to use `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all` for a full expansion, because we have nested macros:

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '#(-> [%]))
;; => (fn* [p1__6995#] [p1__6995#])
```

although, we can also look at it one step at a time:

```
(macroexpand '#(-> [%]))
;; => (fn* [p1__7000#] (-> [p1__7000#]))

(macroexpand '(-> [p1__7000#]))
;; => [p1__7000#]
```

So to answer your question: *There is no next function* in `(-> [%])`. The number of next functions can be any non-negative number, including zero, which is the case with `(-> [%])`.

Answer (score 0):

@Rulle gives an exhaustive explanation of the details.

May I point out the most important part?  [Your reference](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_gotcha) from `Clojure.org` says:

```
;; DO NOT DO THIS
#([%])
```

So, ***don't do that!*** It is a silly trick that will only cause confusion & pain.  Why would you want that???

Comment: thanks for your post. I am just studying the language, so I just wanted to try it.